# Designing A Freely Spinning Object

Tags: design, motors, prototyping

I'm doing a project that involves spinning up a (roughly) 2.28 kg object to 5000 rpm (via a DC motor) and then letting it continue rotating under its own influence (without any more input from the motor).

See my image:[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwgAB.png)

For my project to work, friction and other forms of resistance must be reduced to a minimum. My initial thought was simply to to use the DC motor itself, but in my experience, most such motors generate excess internal friction. And clearly, a motor that goes on spinning without electrical input will become a generator, thus creating more resistance.

So, does anyone have any suggestions? Preferably something that I could simply buy.

Comment: You’re looking for a clutch?

Comment: Well, it would be useful to find a clutch that's small enough, but really I'm looking for whatever would be connected / disconnected from the clutch. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Or a one-way (Sprague) clutch. The weight of the object is not relevant, other than for the bearing axial load. What *is* important is moment of inertia and the acceleration rate.

Comment: @Transistor, good idea, this would work, it seems.

Comment: Any one-way clutch is going to have drag when it is "disengaged".

Comment: That could be a fun experiment if the critical whirling speed is below 5000 RPM. You might get away with it on the acceleration if you do that quickly enough, but not on the deceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: A plain old ordinary motor with a clutch of some sort that is completely non-contact when it is disengaged.  If losses when you're spinning the thing up don't matter too much, then a rubber drive wheel on a motor that engages the outside circumference of your object (or a wheel on the axle on top) would work.

Option 2: DC motor have "excess" losses because they have permanent magnets in them, that continue to cause losses in the armature iron as they spin.  So use a motor that doesn't have permanent magnets, such as a wound-field DC motor (hard to get, unless you get a universal motor), or an induction motor driven from a VFD to get you above synchronous speed.

There will be a trade-off here: most inexpensive motors of this sort are still not aerodynamically perfect, and may not be happy at 5000 RPM.  Moreover, finding suitable motors that are both off the shelf and as small as your application demands will be a challenge.  You'll have to shop around for a suitable motor (and possibly VFD), and you may not be able to avoid aerodynamic losses unless you're going to operate this in a vacuum.

I think that if I were designing this for production and could specify the motor, I'd want a small induction machine or a variable-reluctance motor -- probably the induction machine.

Comment: What about a BLDC motor?

Comment: A BLDC motor still has permanent magnets, and would still show iron losses when unenergized and spinning.